# EF 6 getting parent record from DB when table has many to many relation with itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to build an organization hierarchy where each team might contain one or many members and/or one or many sub-teams.

To do so, my model is:

```
 public class Team
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> SubTeams { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
 }
```

When adding a migration and updating database, everything seems logical in the table.
EF has added an extra nullable column "Team_Id" where the Id of the parent Team gets stored.

[image: Table Screenshot]

My question is about getting the Id of the parent Team from my model.
I tried adding:

```
public int? Team_Id
```

To my model, but EF considered it as a model change and asked for another migration.

How can I get the value of column Team_Id in my model? getting this info takes too much processing when looping through teams.

Comment: I haven't done any non-EFCore programming in a few years but see if `.HasForeignKey(t=>t.TeamId)` works, or whatever the equivalent API in EF is. Besides, you can always generate a migration and edit it to remove everything from `Up()` and `Down()`.

Answer (score 1):

I always add foreign key in my model. When it adds to the model, EF won't add `Team_Id` .

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> SubTeams { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Team ParentTeam { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this example be helpful.